# SSAS - MDX calculated member

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, cube

I've a fact table that details individual line amounts for orders placed by my organisation.  In this fact, at line level, I've included the total order amount to be used, as it's possible we might need that level of detail at some point.

Here's an example of what I've got:-

```
+------------+------------+---------------+------------+---------------------+
| BookingKey | Booking_ID | Category_FKey | Line_Value | Total_Booking_Value |
+------------+------------+---------------+------------+---------------------+
|          1 |         12 |             8 |        150 |                 700 |
|          2 |         12 |             4 |        150 |                 700 |
|          3 |         12 |             5 |        300 |                 700 |
|          4 |         12 |             4 |        100 |                 700 |
+------------+------------+---------------+------------+---------------------+
```

As you can see, the `Total_Booking_Value` here is the sum of the `Line_Value` for the booking in the example (Booking_ID = 12).

The `Category_FKey` looks up to a Categories dimension.

Using this structure I've created a simple cube and this works fine, mainly.

The issue I have is that I'd like to be able to view the Total `Line_Value` amount, and somehow include the `Total_Booking_Value` alongside it.

So, for example I might add the Categories dimension as a filter and want to filter by say `Category_FKey` = 4.

If this was the case I'd want the aggregates to tell me that the total Line_Value was 250 (for BookingKeys 2 and 4), and the `Total_Booking_Value` should be 700.  Using normal aggregation (ie SUM) I'm getting the `Total_Booking_Value` as 1400 (obviously - because it's adding 700 * 2 for the two rows the cube would return).

So, the way I see it I'd like to create an MDX calculation that somehow takes the `Total_Booking_Value` and gives just the value for the Booking in question.

Should this be done using some kind of average, or division by the Distinct number of items?  I can't figure this out.  I tried something like this:-

```
create member currentcube.measures.[Calculated Booking Value]
as
[Measures].[Total_Booking_Value] / count(Measures.Booking_ID);
```

But this isn't working.

Hopefully this makes sense and you can point me in the right direction.

Comment: What happens if you give Total Booking Value an aggregation function of None rather than Sum?

Comment: The measure just appears as blank in my cube.

Comment: What if you drilldown to the leaf-level for each dimension linked to the fact (so no dimension is at the All member). Do you see the Total Booking Value now?

Comment: Or could you have the booking value as an attribute of the Booking dimension as there appears to be a 1-1 relationship between BookingID and Total Booking Value?

Comment: How would that work?  If it was an attribute then I wouldn't be able to aggregate at any level - it would just give me a load of additional rows in my cube for each Booking ID (unless I'm misunderstanding completely).

Comment: Ok. If you create a Count of Rows measure for your Fact, and change Total Booking Value back to a SUM, and then have a calculated measure like [Measures].[Total Booking Value] / [Measures].[Fact Count] this will work for the Booking dimension leaf level (I have successfully tested this). You will probably have to add a SCOPE statement to handle the [Booking].[All] member has the calculated measure will make no sense. Let me know if you want me to give you a more detailed answer.

Comment: This didn't work - the figure I got back was much lower than the expected Total Booking Value figure for some reason.  I think this is because of the fact that the Total Booking Value is obviously not always the same figure, due to different Booking IDs. Once aggregated it's not just a case of dividing one number by the other.  The calculation would need to take place at Booking_ID level - ie divide the Total Booking Value by the number of Booking IDs

Comment: It will work at the leaf level of the Booking dimension as long as the Total Booking Value in your Fact is the same per BookingID e.g. for BookingID 1 the Total Booking Value must always be 100. However, it won't work at any level other than leaf level, so would be of limited use. I will see if I can think of anything else. But I wouldn't hold out much hope...

Answer (score 0):

I find it strange that booking_ID is a measure - intuitively it strikes me as something that would be an attribute and therefore a hierarchy - in which case you'd be able to do the count like this:

```
[Measures].[Total_Booking_Value] 
/ 
COUNT(EXISTING [Booking].[Booking_ID].[Booking_ID].members)
```

Comment: Booking_ID isn't a measure - it's in the Fact table, but it's a degenerate dimension.  I'll give your suggestion a try tomorrow and let you know how I get on.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward solution would be to have two fact tables: one with granularity booking key and one with granularity booking id. The first would contain all columns except total booking value, and the second would contain columns booking id and total booking value.

Then each of both measures would easily be summable.

The reference type between the second fact table and the category dimension could be configures as many-to-many via the first fact table. Thus, you would see the full values of the involved bookings for each selected category, automatically eliminating double counting.

Comment: How would this solve my cube issue, where I might want to filter by category but still keep a column that contains the Total Booking Value along with the other measures?